# Is every positive ancient solution of heat equation to be constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $u$ be a positive solution of heat equation:
$$
\partial _tu(x,t)=\Delta u(x,t)
$$
on $\mathbb R^n \times(-\infty,0)$.

Then must $u$ be a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $u(x,t) = \exp(|k|^2 t + k \cdot x)$

Comment: Would it be constant if we put the bounded condition on $u$？